# How to change multiple cells from relative to absolute without changing references?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The cells I selected in [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgVhk.png) are relatively the same. What I want to do now, is reuse that upper table by copying the lower table below, but don't change values. I was thinking if I could at the same time selected cells turn to absolute by pressing `F4`, I could easily copy them below without changing anything if I could apply `F4` for all selected cells. I found that it should work by pressing `F4` while selected multiple cells [here](https://www.causal.app/excel-shortcuts/f4-shortcut-excel#:%7E:text=To%20use%20the%20F4%20shortcut%2C%20simply%20select%20the%20cell%20reference,then%20pressing%20the%20F4%20key.), but for me Excel says `"We couldn't find what you are looking for"`. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Note according to your reference, I think it is implied that you can use `F4` on multiple cell references selected *within one formula* while in edit mode - not when you are selecting multiple cells. Its actually surprising that this doesn't work, or that Excel doesn't have a "keep references as is" paste special option on the paste menu.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to "Show Formulas"
2. Select and copy <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> all the formulae
3. Open notepad and paste <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
4. Go back to Excel and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
5. Go back to Notepad, select all and copy <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
6. Go back to Excel and paste <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
7. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to disable "Show Formulas"